# MongooseError: Operation `infos.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

Good day everyone, I am beginner in backend development, I encountered a problem trying to connect my server to my database. This is my code from my server:

```
const express = require("express")
const {default:mongoose} = require("mongoose")

const app = express();
const Info = require("./models/info.js")

app.set("views engine", "ejs")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/footballinfo").
then(()=>{console.log("Mongoose server has started")
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("Unsuccessful")
})

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const infos = await Info.find()
    res.render("index.ejs", {title:"Home", news})
})
```

and this is the code from my database:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const infoSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required:[true, "Title cannot be blank"]
        },
        snippet: {
            type: String,
            required:[true, "Snippet cannot be blank"]
        },
        body: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "The Information is blank"]
        },
    },
    {timestamps: true}
)

const Info = mongoose.model("Info", infoSchema)

module.exports=Info
```

this is the reply i got from my terminal:

```
server is running
Unsuccessful
C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `infos.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Please would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Did you start the `mongod` process on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a problem in connecting to **Mongoose**.
Make sure to log the connection error first before any request to mongoose.
try updating your connection code to this:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/footballinfo").
then(()=>{console.log("Mongoose server has started")
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.error(err)
})
```

This will give you why your connection was unsuccessful.
Also `mongoose.connect()` behaves asynchronously so handle that before making any request to the server.